# minimize absolute function in Java

Tags: java, linear-programming

I'm looking into absolute function minimization problem in Java. Can anyone suggest libraries and solutions?

I downloaded `apache common math3`, however, could not find related functions to create linear function to minimize absolute functions.

Simply, I am looking into writing below functions in Java.

```
f(x) = b + | x - a | + d + | x - c | +  f + | x - e |
```

I've edited this problem a bit for my second problem, here b, d, f are also linear functions.

```
b = a1x + b1
d = a2x + b2
f = a3x + b3
```

Comment: Can you explain why Math.abs( x - a ) isn't a solution?

Comment: probably, because He don't even know there is Math.abs()

Comment: `abs()` deserves some warning: it is non-smooth (non-differentiable) so it may cause problems for some models and some solvers. I usually reformulate these constructs.

Comment: @Aubin I think I am solving convex problem and it should be among values given a, c, and e. And I agree with the solution below.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki I know the meaning of abs, but here b, d, f are also derived functions of x.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for the comment. Can you share how do you reformulate it?

Comment: Depending on the model one could think of using a quadratic function, LP techniques like variable splitting or using a smooth approximation. Of course using the median as shown by Andy is a very clever approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are summing N terms of the form `|x - a_i|`, consider the gradient as `x` increases from negative infinity:

- At negative infinity, and for most of the left-hand number line, the gradient is `-N`;
- As you pass the minimum of the `a_i` values, the gradient increases slightly, to `-N+2`;
- As you pass the next smallest of the `a_i` values, the gradient increases again, to `-N+4`.
- Each further `a_i` passed, the gradient increases by 2;
- At positive infinity, the gradient is `+N`.

So, the gradient starts negative, increases in steps at each of the `a_i` positions, and ends up positive; you're looking for the point or range where the gradient is zero. This will occur "in the middle", i.e. at the median of the values `a_i`.

- If there are an odd number of points, the median will be at a point. This is the case in the question: the minimum is at `median(a, c, e)`.
- If there are an even number of points, the median is between two points. In this case, the function is minimised anywhere between those points.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem.